# Android camera setting image

Tags: android, camera

I know this has been asked but I have been scouring the internet for the correct solution to my problem. I use a camera intent and then try to get the image from the camera and set it to an image view. Everything works great until it is time to go back and set the image. I am able to take the picture but when I click ok it restarts the app with no image. Any ideas on how to get it to actually capture the image and not just restart?

```
public class Submit extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.submit);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your CAMERA_REQUEST to 1337. It worked for me.

edit:
Now I checked and It also worked for 1888 code.

Your code works fine for me.